# I am not able to import python libraries (numpy, matplotlib, PIL ...) to use in my webots simulation

Tags: python, numpy, import, simulation, webots

I am trying to create a simulation using webots in python. Although the libraries (NumPy, matplotlib, etc..) are installed on my ubuntu system, I  cannot import them in my controller!!
how can I use these libraries in my webots controller ??

```
from controller import Robot, DistanceSensor, Motor, CameraSupervisor,Node
import random
import numpy as np


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You should be able to import your python module in Webots as with any regular python script.
Can you please provide an example and the error message you get?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the `numpy` package first. Open terminal and type

```sh
pip install numpy
# or
python -m pip install -U numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with similar error.

Run this command "PYTHON_PATH\Scripts\pip.exe install opencv-python" on cmd.exe if you use Windows otherwise check the link below:

https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots-doc/blob/master/guide/using-python.md